# I am trying to free array of stuct but getting free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000afa010

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
struct cacheline
{
    int x[16];
};
struct cacheline *block = malloc(sizeof(struct cacheline) *size); //malloc for array of stucts
    write_start = clock();
    for (k=0;k<=1000;k=k+1){
        for (i=1;i<=size;i=i+1){
            for(j=0;j<16;j=j+1){
                    block[i].x[j] = j+1; ///some operation
            }
        }
    }
write_stop = clock();
Elapsed_write_time = (double)(write_stop - write_start)/1000 * 16;
printf("Elapsed time: %f\n",Elapsed_write_time);
free(block); //free the araray of structs
```

I am trying to free the array of stucts and I am getting the follwoing error.

Comment: `i=1;i<=size` --> `i = 0; i < size`

Answer (score 1):

You wrote past the end of the array. The last element is `block[999]` but your code writes to `block[1000]` as well.

Comment: I am relatively new to malloc, so should I be iterating the loop for only 999 ?

Comment: @ShreyasManjunath:  All C arrays are zero based, both dynamic and regular.  If you have `SomeType array_name[SOME_SIZE];`, you iterate of `for (int i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE; i++)` unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C always start with index `0` and end at `size-1`. In the loop you access behind the array. It should be:

```
    for (i=0;i < size;i=i+1){
```

And probably same for `k`, though I can't find how is it used.

Comment: I think `k` is simply a repeat count to make the code take a semi-reasonable amount of time.  Also intrigued by `i = i + 1` rather than `i++` — copying from question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I believe so. Still it loops 1001 times which is inconsistent with the divide at the end of the program.

Comment: I knew i should be iterating from 0 to 999 but did 1 to 1000.....
Btw i work on system verilog with i=i+1 so used to typing that

Comment: Yeah, and the multiply by 16 is funny too; it should be `… / (1001 * 16)`, with the loops as written.